# How to filter data after gridComplete - client side (jqGrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have custom made filters (not jqgrid's filter bar) that work fine but I would like to execute filtering after data in the grid are reloaded. I know that `DoSearch` function is executed but I don't see any result of filtering.

This is the grid (contains some of my experiments):

```
function PopulateMainGrid() {
    $.jgrid.gridUnload('#list2');
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: 'service.aspx?method=yxc',
        datatype: "XML",
        colNames: [' ', 'id', 'CustomerID', 'Material name', 'Unit', 'Producer', 'Cat. Nr.', 'Supplier', 'Order', 'Project', 'Ordered', 'OrderHeadID', 'Material type', 'Amount', 'Received', 'Remaining', 'state'],
        colModel: [
            { name: ' ', index: ' ', hidden: true },
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
            { name: 'CustomerID', index: 'CustomerID', hidden: true },
            { name: 'MaterialName', index: 'MaterialName', width: 300 }

            ...
            ...
            ...

        ],
        rowNum: 25, rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
        pager: '#pager2',
        height: 580,
        width: 1100,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        ondblClickRow: function (id) { OpenCard(id); },
        //gridComplete: function (data) { setTimeout(DoSearch(), 2000);  }
        postData: function () { DoSearch(); }
    });
```

This is the function that performs filtering:

```
function DoSearch() {

    var grid = $("#list2");
    var filter = {
        "groupOp": "AND", "rules":
            [
                { "field": "Unit", "op": "cn", "data": $("#cmbsUnits  option:selected").text() },
                { "field": "ProducerName", "op": "cn", "data": $("#cmbsProducers  option:selected").text() },

                 ...
                 ...
                 ...

            ]
    };
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { filters: filter } });
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
}
```

XML as response:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
   <page>1</page>
   <total>1</total>
   <records>7</records>
   <row id="">
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[1-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-09-18 10:13:45]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="">
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[2-10-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-02 15:23:14]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="">
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[1-10-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-02 15:26:37]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="86">
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[86]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[test1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[unit 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[prod 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[111]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[sup 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[3-10-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-19 08:33:33]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[67]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Custom item]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[33]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[9]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[24]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="84">
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[84]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[test 2]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[unit 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[prod 2]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[222]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[sup 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-19 10:30:50]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[64]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Custom item]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[33]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[33]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="85">
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[85]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[test1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[unit 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[prod 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[111]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[sup 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-19 10:30:50]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[64]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Custom item]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[12]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[12]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
   <row id="87">
      <cell />
      <cell><![CDATA[87]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[35]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[test 2]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[unit 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[prod 2]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[222]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[sup 1]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4-10-2018]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[aa]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[2018-10-19 10:31:59]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[68]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[Custom item]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[22]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[22]]></cell>
      <cell><![CDATA[4]]></cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

I would like to perform filtering after everything is finished on the grid after refresh. `DoSearch` Function **is** triggered but I don't see any effect.

Any idea is welcome.

EDIT:

jqGrid  5.1.1

Comment: The correct way is to use it in gridComplete event - just uncomment the line. Puting  the function in postData in this way is wrong. I highly recommend you in your case to check your server side code - does the search actually work on your server

Comment: @TonyTomov that is the problem, on gridComplete function is executed but rows aren't filtered. Everything should be done on client side.

Comment: Sorry missed loadonce param. In colModel index and name can't have empty value as you have such one. Can you please post some test xml response and the full colModel or maybe prepare example in jsfiddle? By the way which version of jqGrid is  used?

Comment: @TonyTomov I have updated with version and xml response but I have to emphasise that DoSearch works perfectly if it is triggered by user. Problem is to dynamically filter after grid load.

Comment: @dllhell: You use currently commercial ["Guriddo jqGrid JS"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). The alternative fork of jqGrid - ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), has the feature, which you need. One need just add `forceClientSorting: true` option additionally to `loadonce: true` and `search: true`, `postData: { filters: filter }`. As the result free jqGrid will filter and sort the data returned from the server and display the first page of the results. No additional reloading of the grid with `reloadGrid` is required.

Comment: @dllhell:  Another remark: the usage of ` name: ' '` isn't allowed in any version of jqGrid. You have to fix the definition of the `name` property of the first column and to use *any* unique name, which don't contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and in case of gridComplete evet this bring you to infinite loop since of the triggering the grid. In order this to be executed correct it is needed to set somewhere a global flag and and when the grid complete executes to set this flag so that the DoSearch function should be not executed. Here is a working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dynamic = false;
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    gridComplete: function (data) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            if( !dynamic) { 
                DoSearch();
            }
        }, 1000);
    },
    ....
});

function DoSearch() {
    var grid = $("#jqGrid");
    var filter = {
        "groupOp": "AND", "rules":
            [
                { "field": "name", "op": "eq", "data": 'Client 1' },
                { "field": "tax", "op": "gt", "data": '200' }
            ]
    };
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { filters: filter } });
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
    dynamic = true;
}
```

In case of future dynamic search you will need just to set this variable to false.

Here is the [demo example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/loading_data/xml_dynamic/)